# Selecting G-code files from SD with serial

Tags: marlin, g-code, prusa-i3-rework

I'm doing a project for college connecting an app made with app inventor to a Raspberry Pi and then using the RPi to make a printing queue for a Prusa P3 Steel.

The thing is that I already have the comm between the app and the RPi but I need to connect the RPi to the Arduino via USB and select the G-code files that are in the SD card of the Prusa to print. I don't know where should I put the function in the Marlin code or how to manage the serial port read function.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you connect the prusa via USB to the Rpi? That way you can feed the G-code directly and keep the queue on the Pi.

Comment: Just out of interest: Are you using [MIT App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/) for iOS or [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.org/) for Android?

Answer (score 4):

You can send the G Codes to select and print a file over the serial connection.

- List the files

  > M20
- Select a file name

  > M23 filename.gco
- Start/Resue the print

  > M24

See https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code for more information M20 through M39 are the ones for interfacing with SD Card files.